# Ajax Call returns undefined when async is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

have  function and it's working when async is false, but I want the same functionality (by which I mean return value) but with async is true .

```
  function Call(param, proc) {
    var url = "../../DataManager/DataManagment.aspx/DataSelector";
    var ret;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "data": param,
            "action": proc
        }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            ret = data;
        },
        async: false,
        error: errorFn
    });
    return ret.d;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You [can't return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) from asynchronous code like AJAX. Instead you need to reconsider your function a littler.

So you either need to use a callback and call it in success function or better just return promise object:

```
function Call(param, proc) {
    var url = "../../DataManager/DataManagment.aspx/DataSelector";
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            data: param,
            action: proc
        }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        error: errorFn
    });
}

Call(params, process).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thank You So Much Brother , Its Work For Me.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like:

```
 function callServerAsync(){
   $.ajax({
        url: '...',
        success: function(response) {

            successCallback(response);

        }
    });
  }

  function successCallback(responseObj){
     alert(JSON.stringify(responseObj)); // Only applicable to JSON response
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

For async=true; return statement will not serve your purpose. Instead go for some callback like below:

```
function Call(param, proc, callBackFunc) {
    var url = "../../DataManager/DataManagment.aspx/DataSelector";
    var ret;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "data": param,
            "action": proc
        }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            ret = data;

            if(typeof callBackFunc == 'function')
            {
                callBackFunc(ret.d);
            }
        },
        async: true,
        error: errorFn
    });

}
```

And call your function as:

```
function myCallBackFunc(obj)
{
    alert(obj);
}

//call the actual function like:
Call(param, proc,myCallBackFunc);
```

Answer (score 1):

mate, you problem is :return ret.d;

you should have you return ret.d; inside the success function, otherwise, return ret.d will return immediately no matter you ajax have been success or not, that's why when you force ajax run sync it works, but not when async because that time ret is only defined but not assigned value,  check this  :

```
function Call(param, proc) {
var url = "../../DataManager/DataManagment.aspx/DataSelector";
var ret;
$.ajax({
url: url,
type: "POST",
datatype: "json",
data: JSON.stringify({
    "data": param,
    "action": proc
}),
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
success: function (data) {
    ret = data;
    return ret.d;
},
async: true,
error: errorFn
});

}
```

Comment: That ruins the entire point of making it asynchronous as the program will wait for the function to return the value, which basically makes it synchronous

Comment: brother its not returning any value when i return ret.d in success function.