# Ajax-POST succeeds only Async is false

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying POST ajax call to my back end.
It is working fine if I set `async: false,` but if I remove that it is failing and return undefined in error section

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        url: "http://localhost:8000/student/queue/create",
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 600000,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);

        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log("ERROR : ", e.responseText);
            alert("ERROR : "+  e.responseText);

        }
    });
```

Calling my ajax function from button onclick

```
<button type="submit" id="submit-createqueue" class="btn feedback glass" onclick="sendformDataToBackend()">Submit</button>
```

I tried [Ajax Call returns undefined when async is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707110/ajax-call-returns-undefined-when-async-is-true) but that also not working

```
function Call(data) {

    return $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8000/student/queue/create",
        type: "POST",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 600000,

        error: function (e) {
        console.log("ERROR : ", e.responseText);
        alert("ERROR : "+  e.responseText);
        }

    });
}

Call(data).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    alert("test")
});
```

Comment: You need to stop the form submission that's also happening when you click the submit button. It works with `async: false` because it blocks processing while the request is in process - which is exactly why you shouldn't use it. I'd also strongly suggest you stop using `on*` event attributes. Use unobtrusive event handlers instead

Comment: Thanks, I moved <button type="submit" id="submit-createqueue" class="btn feedback glass" onclick="sendformDataToBackend()">Submit</button>     outside of form tag, Now it is working for async also

Comment: Glad you got it working, but that's not really a workable solution as it breaks accessibility functionality. I added an answer for you which gives a better method - by hooking to the `submit` event of your `<form>` element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop the form submission that's also happening when you click the submit button. It works with `async: false` because it blocks processing while the request is in process - which is exactly why you shouldn't use it.

I'd also strongly suggest you stop using `on*` event attributes. Use unobtrusive event handlers instead.

As you're using jQuery, you can achieve both of those using this code:

```
$('#yourFormElement').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var data = // your logic to get form data here...

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    url: "http://localhost:8000/student/queue/create",
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    timeout: 600000,
    success: function (data) {
      console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
    },
    error: function (e) {
      console.log("ERROR : ", e.responseText);
      alert("ERROR : " +  e.responseText);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with input type button replaced with submit button

Comment: This isn't really a workable solution as it affects accessibility standards.